# How can I access a file shared by other app Android

Tags: java, android

I need to share from Whatsapp a voice message to my app. I have already added this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Now I have

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri audioUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Then I need to send the file to server using post method. I tried `new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getPath()))`, but getPath() returns `/item/141129fe-ba1a-4e2e-aca1-402b6484d2e3` and `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"` is thrown. How should I access the file?

Comment: InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(audioUri);

Comment: Thank you for a hint! But how can I use input stream with FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel(); ?

Comment: I have no idea. And why would you use FileChannel?

Comment: I need to write the streamt to URLConnection

Comment: Of course. But why would you use FileChannel for it? You can make a loop to read from the inputstream and write that to the outputstream.

Comment: Thank you very much! The issue wasn't in the write section, but the input stream helped me a lot!!!